# JSON and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

How do you return a serialized JSON object to the client side using ASP.NET MVC via an AJAX call?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the controller you can just return a JsonResult:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    ... // Populate myObject
    return new JsonResult{ Data = myObject };
}
```

The form of the Ajax call will depend on which library you're using, of course. Using jQuery it would be something like:

```
$.getJSON("/controllerName/MyAction", callbackFunction);
```

where the `callbackFunction` takes a parameter which is the data from the XHR request.

Comment: How would you pass parameters to the MyAction?

Comment: No formatting in a comment, but...  $.getJSON("/controllerName/MyAction", { id: 7 }, callbackFunction);

Answer (score 10):

Depending on your syntax preferences, the following also works:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    return Json(new {Data = myObject});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the Small block of code for just understand , how we can use JsonResults in MVC Controllers.

```
   public JsonResult ASD()
    {
    string aaa = "Hi There is a sample Json";
    return Json(aaa);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also System.Web.Script.Serialization; as below

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public ActionResult MyAction(string myParam)
{

    return  new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myObject);
}
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("MyAction","MyMethod")',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "myParam": "your data" }),
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send JSON in response to a GET, you'll need to explicitly allow the behavior by using JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet.

```
public JsonResult Foo()
{
    return Json("Secrets", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```