# Making flexible C# code in MVC2 for Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-2

Thanks to [Darin Dimitrov's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888490/optimizing-c-code-in-mvc-controller) I got a big step further in understanding good MVC code, but I'm having some problems making it flexible.

I implemented Darin's suggested solution, and it works perfectly for single controllers. However I'm having some trouble implementing it with some flexibility. What I'm looking for is this;

- To be able to make dynamic column names in json

> Instead of using "Column1: 'value', ..." and
>   "Column2: 'value', ..." inside the json, I'd like to
>   use for example "id: 'value', ..." and "place: 'value' ..." for
>   one stored procedure, and "animal" and
>   "type" in another (inside the json
>   format).

- To be able to make dynamic amounts of columns dependent on which stored procedure is called

> Some stored procedures I'll want to
>   read more than 2 rows from, is there a
>   smart way of accomplishing that?

- To be able to make numeric (floats and integers) rows from the database be presented inside the json without quotes

Like this (name and age);

```
{
    Column1: "John",
    Column2: 53
},
```

I would be very grateful for any feedback and suggestions / code examples I can get here. Even imperfect ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using anonymous objects? So for example you could have a method in your repository that returns `System.Object`:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    object GetModel(int id);
}
```

Then depending on the stored procedure you are calling you would return a different anonymous type:

```
public class RepositorySql : IRepository
{
    public object GetModel(int id) 
    {
        // TODO: Call a stored procedure and depending on the procedure you are 
        // calling return a different anonymous type, for example:
        return new 
        {
            Column1 = "value1",
            Column2 = "value2",
        }
    }
}
```

and finally in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var model = _repository.GetModel(id);
    return Json(model);
}
```

Now of course the view consuming this action would need to know what columns are there in the JSON object. I would recommend you using some base type instead of `System.Object` from which other models would derive and that would contain common properties.

I don't really know your requirements but if it is simply a matter of returning some list of values that would vary based on the stored procedure you could simply return an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out again! Yes, I should have said, the point of these calls are only to feed a number of JavaScripts with JSONified data.

I can't believe I didn't think of that myself, I will get to work immediately. Just leaving this open in hopes of getting more suggestions Thanks again Darin!